# Integration tests for plotly.js

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, integration-testing, plotly

Need to test the line chart, scatter chart, spider chart etc created using plotly.js using any automation framework/tools. Following are few of the targeted verifications:

-Get data points (markers) count

-Get each data point (marker) value

-Get data points css

-Get legends css

-Handling out of the box action header items

-Zoom in/out

Have tried with java-selenium but can’t find data points (markers) in DOM to get the required styling and values.

Can anyone please help in this aspect to how to perform integration testing for these charts here?
Link for demo chart - https://plot.ly/javascript/line-and-scatter/

The same has been integrated as it is in our scenario.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML, your code trials and error stack trace

Comment: Hi @neetigya goel, can you share some plotly.js based example website link which shows charts?

Comment: Updated the documentation link here @AliCSE

Comment: Sorry @neetigya goel, I also don't have any idea on that. Try  to search `Ocular` in the google, that may helpful